# Is this slide made unnecessarily hard?

Tags: guitar, technique, tablature, fingerstyle-guitar

[image]

Sliding from 3 to 5 and then hitting 2? Do I need to stretch my hands that much? Or is this made unnecessarily hard?

Comment: You can plau the bass string on the 2nd fret with your thumb, this is quite easy.

Comment: If you use your pinky for that slide, the stretch is not big at all... you still have 1 finger in each fret, which is considered normal (not even a stretch). Do you have issues playing it that way?

Comment: If I use my picky to slide and then use my index finger on the second fret, it is quite the stretch, maybe it becomes easier the more I do it?

Comment: @user65342: Exactly that. Without wanting to sound like looking down, this is quite a normal stretch. Just keep at it, without overexerting yourself. You will get there. I still have fond 40 year old memories of Bach's prelude in D minor (BWV 999) where at one point there is an F on the low E string (1st fret), with a pinky barre over the G,B and E string on the 5th fret. At the time I thought they were all completely crazy. Turns out you get there, even in a few weeks to months time (depending on the level of determination and dexterity).

Comment: I posted the beginning of the song as well, might be different somehow now? I think barring the second fret works best, not sure

Answer (score 2):

Not at all (if you don't have a ultra-small hand).

My advice would be to play it just as it is written. The reason is that as you play more and more, your hand will be progressively more able to stretch, so after some time, you will be absolutely OK with it.

On top of that, stretches like this just occur quite frequently on the guitar (they often arise when you try to play a bass line independent of your melody), and often they are far worse. Because of that, it's no use trying to avoid or work around them -- you will hit another one sooner or later. (For instance, you can get a very useful G major "shape" if you stop the low E at the 3rd fret and the high E at the 7th (or even 10th) fret.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a crucial piece of information missing from this TAB.  What fingering is suggested for this?  If you slide using the ring finger (or pinky) your index will be free to grab the 2nd fret and should not be a problem. Whether or not that seems reasonable depends on the notes before the 2 you've shown.

If you really want help please post the entire line so we can see how this phase fits into the bigger picture.  As some have mentioned the thumb is also an option.

Comment: Edited it and posted the beginning of the song

Comment: Beautiful.   It makes sense now

Comment: I can't seem to find a good fingering for this, I think barring the second fret works best, not sure

Answer (score 1):

As written it's a somewhat difficult passage.  The performance is much clearer when you consider the standard notation: the A on the first string has to be held until you hit the B note tabbed on the sixth string later in the measure.

Since the B is two frets higher than the A, you'd need to do the slide with your ring finger, then reach a bit with the index finger to barre the 2nd fret for the E, A, and C# notes.  You'd then have to continue holding the A while you stretch to play the 6th string B with your little finger. It's a bit awkward.

This is a good example of how tab shows you only ONE way to do something, and an alternative might make more sense.  I'd probably make the slide with the little finger, and then play all of the next notes on the 2nd fret with an index finger barre, playing the B on the 5th string, then moving to 7th position for the next beat and a half.

Assuming it's correctly noted, it's a good exercise - one of the biggest differences between pros and amateurs isn't whether they play the notes in the right place... it's whether they hold the notes for the right length.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but what do you mean It has to be held? when you're sliding from 3 to 5, the 5 must be held? Is that why there's a long line on the normal notation? Is this what's called a tie?

Comment: The A (the note you're sliding into on 5) is a longer duration than the other notes in the measure.  There is a tie - that's the curved line that extends from the right side of the A in the standard notation - but even without it, the A is a half note, so it has to last for two beats (plus the tie)